# Responsive `addWebGLHeatmap` with crosstalk and leaflet in

Tags: r, leaflet, crosstalk

I make a leaflet map with a responsive heatmap using `addHeatmap`. Unfortunately, this kind of tool it is not enough useful because two main problems: 1) The heatmap is redrawed with each new level of zoom and 2) you can not make the heatmap and the points in a separated group each one.

It is possible a similar solution with `addWebGLHeatmap`?

There is the code for the `addHeatmap` solution, following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64175501/responsive-heatmap-with-crosstalk-and-leaflet-in-r)

```
library(crosstalk)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(dplyr)

# Wrap data frame in SharedData
sd <- SharedData$new(quakes[sample(nrow(quakes), 10),])

bscols(widths=c(3,9),
  # Create a filter input
  filter_slider("mag", "Magnitude", sd, column=~mag, step=0.1),
  leaflet(sd) %>% 
    addTiles() %>% 
    addMarkers() %>% 
    addHeatmap(layerId="heatmap") %>%
    removeHeatmap("heatmap") %>%
    htmlwidgets::onRender("
      function(el,x){
        var myMap = this;
        var coord_state;
        var coords;
        
        function get_markers(){
          coord_state = [];
          myMap.eachLayer(function(layer){
            if (typeof layer.options.lat != 'undefined'){
              coord_state.push([layer.options.lat, layer.options.lng, 0.5]);
            }
          })
          return(coord_state)
        }
        
        function update_layer(){
          coords = get_markers()
          heat1.setLatLngs(coords);
          heat1.redraw();
        }
        
        var heat1 = L.heatLayer(get_markers(), {radius: 25}).addTo(myMap);
        myMap.on('layerremove', update_layer);
        myMap.on('layeradd', update_layer);
      }
    "))
```

Comment: How many markers are you planning on plotting? Could you also clarify the two main problems. What behaviour do you expect when the map is zoomed? What functionality do you wan't from separating the heatmap and points into different groups?

Comment: Around 2-3K. About the berhaivoiour when the map is zoomed, I expect the heatmap remain stable. addWebGLHeatmap uses a distance criteria. Thats why I asked a solution adWebGLHeatmap alike. Last, sometimes users may wnt to observe just the points or just the heatmap so the funcionality is that they can disable the point layer or the heatmap layer if they want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method is kind of a hack, but still should be able to work with `addWebGLHeatmap`. It adds two sets of identical markers and hides one which controls the heatmap. This allows for the layer control. A working example can be found here:

https://rpubs.com/Jumble/leaflet_webgl_heatmap

Below is the code that produced this. This code solves the main two problems although it struggles if you wan't to plot over 1000 points.

Rather than using crosstalk it might be better to use a combination of something like `leafgl`, `shiny` and `addWebGLHeatmap`  if you are wanting to plot thousands of points.

```
n <- 200
data <- data.frame(id = seq(1, n*2), lat = rnorm(n, 0, 15), long = rnorm(n, 0, 15), group=c(rep("Heatmap",n), rep("Markers", n)), mag=rep(as.integer(runif(n, 0, 20)),2))
sd <- SharedData$new(data)

bscols(widths=c(3,9),
       filter_slider("mag", "Magnitude", sd, column=~mag, step=0.1),
       leaflet(sd, options=leafletOptions(preferCanvas = TRUE)) %>% 
         addTiles() %>% 
         leaflet::setView(lat=0, lng=0, zoom=4) %>%
         addMarkers(group=~group) %>%
         leaflet.extras::addWebGLHeatmap(layerId = "heatmapwebgl") %>%
         leaflet.extras::removeWebGLHeatmap("heatmapwebgl") %>%
         addLayersControl(overlayGroups = c("Heatmap", "Markers"), options=layersControlOptions(collapsed=FALSE)) %>%
         htmlwidgets::onRender("
          function(el,x){
            var myMap = this;
            var coord_state;
            
            // hide heatmap markers 
            setTimeout(function(){
              myMap.eachLayer(function(layer){
                if (layer.options.group=='Heatmap'){
                  layer.setOpacity(0);
                  layer.getElement().style.pointerEvents = 'none';
                }
              })
            }, 100)
            
            function get_markers(){
              coord_state = [];
              myMap.eachLayer(function(layer){
                if (layer.options.group=='Heatmap'){
                  coord_state.push([layer.options.lat, layer.options.lng, 0.5]);
                  layer.getElement().style.pointerEvents = 'none';
                }
              })
              return(coord_state)
            }
            
            function redraw_heatmap(){
              heatmap.setData(get_markers());
            }
            
            var heatmap = L.webGLHeatmap({size: 1000000,units: 'm',alphaRange: 1});
            heatmap.setData(get_markers());
            myMap.addLayer(heatmap);
            
            myMap.on('layerremove', redraw_heatmap);
            myMap.on('layeradd', redraw_heatmap);
          }
      "))
```

Below for Circle Markers

```
n <- 200
data <- data.frame(id = seq(1, n*2), lat = rnorm(n, 0, 15), long = rnorm(n, 0, 15), group=c(rep("Heatmap",n), rep("Markers", n)), mag=rep(as.integer(runif(n, 0, 20)),2))
sd <- SharedData$new(data)

bscols(widths=c(3,9),
       filter_slider("mag", "Magnitude", sd, column=~mag, step=0.1),
       leaflet(sd) %>% 
         addTiles() %>% 
         leaflet::setView(lat=0, lng=0, zoom=4) %>%
         addCircleMarkers(group=~group, opacity=~ifelse(group=="Heatmap", 0, 0.5), fillOpacity=~ifelse(group=="Heatmap", 0, 0.2)) %>%
         leaflet.extras::addWebGLHeatmap(layerId = "heatmapwebgl") %>%
         leaflet.extras::removeWebGLHeatmap("heatmapwebgl") %>%
         addLayersControl(overlayGroups = c("Heatmap", "Markers"), options=layersControlOptions(collapsed=FALSE)) %>%
         htmlwidgets::onRender("
          function(el,x){
            var myMap = this;
            var coord_state;
            
            function get_markers(){
              coord_state = [];
              myMap.eachLayer(function(layer){
                if (layer.options.group=='Heatmap'){
                  coord_state.push([layer.options.lat, layer.options.lng, 0.5]);
                  layer.getElement().style.pointerEvents = 'none';
                }
              })
              return(coord_state)
            }
            
            function redraw_heatmap(){
              heatmap.setData(get_markers());
            }
            
            var heatmap = L.webGLHeatmap({size: 1000000,units: 'm',alphaRange: 1});
            heatmap.setData(get_markers());
            myMap.addLayer(heatmap);
            
            myMap.on('layerremove', redraw_heatmap);
            myMap.on('layeradd', redraw_heatmap);
          }
      "))
```

Comment: Your answers are always Nice!

Comment: I have a question: I tried to make it with ´addCircleMarkers´ instead of ´addMarkers´ ant didnt showed the heatmap nor hide the markers. How i can solve it using addCircleMarkers?

Comment: @ArmandoGonzálezDíaz Added circle markers to answer above